# While running query via chaincode getting error "Channel channel_Name has been shutdown."

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, couchdb

Trying to run couchdb query via chanincode but getting error `"Channel channel_Name has been shutdown."`

`Network network = gateway.getNetwork(channelName); Contract contract = network.getContract(ChaincodeName);`

I am able to get the contract using above code but when I am trying to query it throwing exception.

I tried searching for exception but did not got much help.

Comment: So the code you're showing works, and the code that doesn't work you don't show? You should edit your question to show a: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)